# how to fix this menu style so that text does not overlap the color bars

Tags: html, css

I would like the text of the menu items to be a little further from the color bars, but can't figure out how. Getting the same result in Chrome and IE11.

```css
  .smenu a {
      display: block;
      color: black;
      padding: 16px 1px;
      margin: 9px 5px;
      text-decoration:none;
      width: 4px;
      background: #18dcff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="smenu">
  <div>
    <div class="item" id="messages">
      <div class="smenu">
        <a href="#a">New</a>
        <a href="#a">Sent Items</a>
        <a href="#a">Spam</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As is, your code is prone to issues. You shouldn't have a width on your a just to define your background. You should use a border instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a "colored border" then you should also use the border property to get the desired result. you can then define the distance to it with `padding`

```css
.smenu a {
      display: block;
      color: black;
      padding: 16px 20px; /* change this to change distance */
      margin: 9px 5px;
      text-decoration:none;
      border-left:4px solid #18dcff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="smenu">
  <div>
    <div class="item" id="messages">
      <div class="smenu">
        <a href="#a">New</a>
        <a href="#a">Sent Items</a>
        <a href="#a">Spam</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```